# Alt+F10 to maximise window in 12.04 with gnome-classic no effects?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, window-manager, gnome-classic

How can I use Alt+F10 to maximise window in 12.04 with gnome-classic no effects? I was able to use it in 11.10, but now, if I am in gnome-terminal and I want to maximise it, I get a symbol `;3~` and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to Applications > System Tools > Preferences > Control Center >> Keyboard >>> Shortcuts (Tab) and choose 'Windows'. Now click on 'Maximize Window' and press 'Alt+F10' to set the shortcut.

There are a lot of useful shortcuts that can be set here including 'Alt+F4' for 'Close window', 'Alt+F9' for 'Minimize window', 'Super+D' (Super stands for the Windows key on most keyboards) for Navigation > 'Hide all normal windows' for Show Desktop and finally 'Alt+Tab' for Navigation > 'Switch Applications'.